# Need an Excel formula to calculate accrued vacation on a bi-weekly basis

Tags: excel-formula

I need an Excel formula to calculate accrued vacation on a bi-weekly basis. Input variables are 'start date', 'accrued days decimal value'. Employees earn 10 days a year for first 4 years. At five years they accrue 20 days a year.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I had a quick go at based on the current date.

You can add an extra columns for the Bi weekly by picking an exact date instead of TODAY() (hint another cell) and finding the mid point of the week in yet another cell.

I always recommend building the formulae up in bits and then perhaps hiding the columns you don't want to see, rather than trying to create a complex formula that's hard to maintain in a single cell.

on Row 2

- Col A : Person Name
- Col B : Start Date (date)
- Col C : Number years since start date and Today `=YEARFRAC( B2, TODAY())`
- Col D : Days Accrued under 5 years `=IF(C2<5, C2*10,  50)`
- Col E : Days Accrued over 5 years `=IF(C2<5, 0, C2-5)*20`
- Col F : Total `=D2+E2`

[image]